# Pylint error E1136 when creating numpy array with random values

Tags: python, numpy, pylint

Could somebody explain why Pylint is complaining? Is my code wrong and if so, what would be a good alternative?

My Python (version 3.6.5) code:

```
""" Test """

import numpy as np

XDATA = np.random.rand(100)
print(XDATA[:10])
```

Pylint (version 2.4.0) output:

```
test.py:6:6: E1136: Value 'XDATA' is unsubscriptable (unsubscriptable-object)

--------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at -6.67/10 (previous run: -6.67/10, +0.00)
```